# Does Channel<T> support multiple ChannelReaders and ChannelWriters, or only one of each?

Tags: c#, system.threading.channels

The documentation for [Channel.CreateUnbounded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createunbounded?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Channels_Channel_CreateUnbounded__1) says:

> Creates an unbounded channel usable by any number of readers and
>   writers concurrently.

However [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-2?view=netcore-3.1) has properties for a single `ChannelReader` and `ChannelWriter` only, and there doesn't appear to be a way to create a reader/writer explicitly around an existing channel.

I had thought that if you had multiple producers/consumers they should share the same instance of a writer/reader, is this incorrect? Is the "number of readers/writers" talking about concurrent access rather than number of class instances?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the documentation means multiple producers (writers) and consumers (readers). All producers are allowed to use the single `ChannelWriter` of the channel, and all consumers are allowed to use its single `ChannelReader`. No external synchronization is required. The `Channel<T>` class is 100% thread-safe.

**Important:** In case of multiple consumers, each item passed through the channel will be received by only one consumer. The `Channel<T>` doesn't support propagating one element to multiple consumers, like it does the [`BroadcastBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.broadcastblock-1) dataflow block for example.